# Rotate individual shape

Tags: rotation, processing

I'm currently working on replicating a piece of art in Processing. But I'm having an issue with the rotate functionality.

So the image can be found [here](http://www.tate.org.uk/art/images/work/P/P07/P07113_10.jpg). Below you can see my code from Processing. As we can see the differing part is the rotating of the ellipses.

I've tried changing the origin e.g:

```
translate(midpoint - (position*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0), i*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0,)
```

Then rotating and creating the shape at (0,0), but doesn't do what I'd like it to!

Any ideas would be appreciated

This changes the origin to the `x, y` position where I want the ellipse to be drawn at.

```
void setup(){
  size(550,550);
  background(187,182,179);

  midpoint = height/2.0;
  tenth = height/10.0;
  circle_radius = 20.0;
}

float circle_radius = 15.0;
float midpoint;
float tenth;
float base_colour = 0;

float getColour(float x_value){
  float colour_val = ((x_value - 50.0)*255.0)/(450.0-50.0);

  if(floor(colour_val/255.0)%2 == 0){
    return colour_val%255.0;
  }
  return 225.0 - (colour_val%255.0);
}

void draw(){
  noStroke();
  background(187,182,179);
  base_colour += 5.0;
  for(int layer = 0; layer < 2; layer++){
    for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++){
      for (int position = 0; position < 5 - layer; position+=1){
         if(i*tenth > tenth && i*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0 < height - tenth){

           fill(getColour(base_colour + midpoint - position*tenth - layer*tenth/2.0 - (i*tenth - layer*tenth/2.0)));
           //rotate(PI/12.0);
           ellipse(midpoint - (position*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0), i*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0,  2.0*circle_radius/3.0, circle_radius);

           fill(getColour(base_colour + midpoint + position*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0 - (i*tenth - layer*tenth/2.0)));
          // rotate(PI/);
           ellipse(midpoint + position*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0, i*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0, 2.0*circle_radius/3.0, circle_radius);
         }  
      }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue appears to be that the rotate command is applied before the translate, or positioning of the ellipse.

A way to avoid this order of transformations issue is to use a translate(), then the rotate() and then draw your shape at (0, 0).

The second issue is that the rotate of the first ellipse is applied to the second ellipse's rotate - and you need to keep them as discrete operations. We can use pushMatrix() and popMatrix() to achieve this, because every transformation method in between these 2 methods is kept separate from the other transformations on this draw() call.

Here is the code (first line and previous lines in supplied code are unchanged).

```
if(i*tenth > tenth && i*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0 < height - tenth){           
       pushMatrix(); // push and pop matrix will keep the transformations between them separate from other transformations happening in the draw method
         fill(getColour(base_colour + midpoint - position*tenth - layer*tenth/2.0 - (i*tenth - layer*tenth/2.0)));           
         // removing the coordinate calculations from the ellipse command to a translate command (and putting 0, 0, in their place in the ellipse method
         translate(midpoint - (position*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0), i*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0);
         rotate(PI/12.0);           // rotating applied after the translate, so we don't get an order of transformation problem.
         ellipse(0, 0,  2.0*circle_radius/3.0, circle_radius);
       popMatrix();

       pushMatrix(); 
         fill(getColour(base_colour + midpoint + position*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0 - (i*tenth - layer*tenth/2.0)));
         translate(midpoint + position*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0, i*tenth + layer*tenth/2.0);
         rotate(PI/-12.0);          // No divisor supplied in original code so I guessed the opposite number to make the ellipses rotate the opposite way
         ellipse(0, 0, 2.0*circle_radius/3.0, circle_radius);
       popMatrix();
     }
```

Comment: Wow this is great! Thanks sooo much for the help, and the great explanation. The push.pop definitely helps! I was attempting to just revert the translate manually each time and had no luck that way! Thanks again, it looks really awesome!